# A term for a policy that forbids employees storing intellectualy property (e.g. Source Code) on hosted third parties services

Tags: cloud-computing, corporate-policy, cloud-storage

To be honest, I was not sure if this belongs to this board or Law Stack Exchange.

I am searching for a specific term that describes a policy that a company does not allow itself to share its intellectual property with third parties.
A example for this are cloud services hosted by third-parties. It can happen that start-ups use these services for storing documents, sourcecode and databases because they lack the infrastructure. Big companies however, as far as I know, usually have policies which enforce that these services must not be used for said purposes.

I tried to find this under the term "Data Security Policy" but the results do not correpond to that what I am looking for

Comment: idk, but some related terms: air gapped, data ex-filtration, data custody, data retention, internal source control, private repo, etc

Comment: When you want to keep everything on-site and not use any cloud or other external storage services it's called 'in-hose data policy'.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are thinking of, it could be titled in one of the following ways:

**Intellectual Property Policy**

As the work done by employees is likely to be classified as a "trade secret", or "intellectual property" of the company, employees should be able to:

- Recognize what IP belongs to the company.
- Understand that IP of the company shouldn't be shared unless it's required (ex. manufacturing).
- Respect the IP of other companies and holders.

See: https://wustl.edu/about/compliance-policies/intellectual-property-research-policies/intellectual-property/

See: https://www.uspto.gov/intellectual-property-ip-policy

**Copyright and Intellectual Property Policy**

Very much of the same thing, but extending further into the realm of copyrighted works, such as books, papers, magazines, video, and so on.

See: https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/ip/index.htm

**Operational Data Policy**

This might be what you are looking for, as data used for day to day operations could be classified as a "code base" or repository, as well as data gathered from clients.

See: https://web.archive.org/web/20160705201428/http://www.rcmvs.org/documentos/IOM_EMM/v3/V3S10_CM.pdf

**Data Retention Policy**

This focuses on data gathered from clients, and what is done with it. Many implement this as a "Privacy Policy". This can be found on any reputable website, or those required to have one by law.

**Acceptable Usage Policy**

I figured I should add this one in, as it is the over arching name for such a policy. It should lay out how corporate computing and information resources should be used by employees, and who is authorized, and who is not. There is an extensive list and examples online for this type of policy.